# Standard way to create a const set with the value as a union/intersection of two sets in C++?

Tags: c++, stl, constants, constexpr

Suppose I have

```
constexpr std::set<int> a = {1, 2, 3};
constexpr std::set<int> b = {3, 4, 5};
```

And I want to create

```
constexpr std::set<int> c = union(a, b); // {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

Is there a library function to do this without creating my own union/intersection function?

Comment: `std::set` is not `constexpr`-friendly. Did you mean `const`?

Comment: C++20 is supposed to make this possible, isn't it? But that's not here yet.

Comment: [`std::set_intersection`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection)/[`std::set_union`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_union) are `constexpr` since C++20.

Comment: Yes, there are library functions that will do this. But instead of just telling what they are, why don't you try to find them yourself, in your favorite C++ reference source? Knowing where to find and how to read technical documentation is something that every C++ developer needs to learn how to do.

Comment: @DeiDei No, I don't think so. `std::vector` and `std::string` are becoming constexpr, but `std::set` is more challenging, I think.

Comment: @DeiDei: As I understand, you might **use** some containers in constant expression, but result still can't be those container.

Comment: @Brian I'm not in too deep in this, but I thought simply `new` was going to become allowed in a `constexpr` context, which in my mind means everything can be a constant expression.

Comment: Looking at [std::set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/set) there is nothing about any upcoming changes for C++20.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the lambda trick to initialize a `const` variable:

```
// need to capture `a`, `b` if this is at block scope
const std::set<int> c = []() {
    std::set<int> result;
    std::set_union(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(), std::inserter(result, result.end()));
    return result;  // compiler can probably NRVO this
}();
```